# Point input for polyline not acceptable?

Tags: pyqgis, point, line

Input QgsPoint(s) are returning an error in a Polyline creation routine.
Any clues?!

```
    processing.runandload("qgis:polygoncentroids", Base, "memory:CenterNode")
    processing.runandload("qgis:extractnodes", Base, "memory:OuterNodes")
    Center = ftools_utils.getMapLayerByName(unicode("memory:CenterNode"))
    Outer = ftools_utils.getMapLayerByName(unicode("memory:OuterNodes"))

    # create line mesh points
    line_center = []
    featuresC = Center.getFeatures()
    for elem in featuresC:
        xy1 = elem.geometry().asPoint()
        line_center.append(xy1)
    print line_center

    line_ends = []
    featuresO = Outer.getFeatures()
    for elem in featuresO:
        xy2 = elem.geometry().asPoint()
        line_ends.append(xy2)
    print line_ends

    Mesh = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "Mesh", "memory")
    prM = Mesh.dataProvider()
    Mesh.startEditing()
    for i in range(len(line_ends)):
        print line_ends[i]
        print line_center[0]
        seg = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(line_ends[i], line_center[0])
        prM.addFeatures([seg])
        Mesh.updateExtents()
    Mesh.commitChanges()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([Mesh])
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: Screen crop was updated to reflect a printout of the varriables prior to the '.fromPolyline(...' command.

Comment: Proper syntax helped a bit via: seg = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(line_center[0]), QgsPoint(line_ends[i])])    As it now gets past the initial 'QgsPoint' error, yet is blocked at the immediately following 'prM.addFeatures([seg])' bit...

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
    line_center = []
    featuresC = Center.getFeatures()
    for elem in featuresC:
        xy1 = elem.geometry().asPoint()
        center = QgsPoint(xy1)
        line_center.append(center)
    print line_center

    line_ends = []
    featuresO = Outer.getFeatures()
    for elem in featuresO:
        xy2 = elem.geometry().asPoint()
        ends = QgsPoint(xy2)
        line_ends.append(ends)
    print line_ends

    Mesh = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "Mesh", "memory")
    prM = Mesh.dataProvider()
    Mesh.startEditing()
    for i in range(len(line_ends)):
        print line_ends[i]
        print line_center[0]
        seg = QgsFeature()
        seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(line_center[0]), QgsPoint(line_ends[i])]))
        print seg
        prM.addFeatures([seg])
        Mesh.updateExtents()
    Mesh.commitChanges()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([Mesh])
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers([Center.id()])
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers([Outer.id()])
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

[image]

Comment: I would, but the Ui says I cannot commit such until tomorrow?